# Java save config files, multi OS

Tags: java, io

so my program is going to need to crate a file with login information. After that, everytime the program will just run normally, unless the login file gets deleted some how. I want to know of a quick way that I can do this in a multi OS way. I dont want to save the file to a specific part on the disk, because then I have to do it for every OS. What else can I do?

Comment: Considering that there are literally two operating systems to consider (Windows and POSIX), some OS-specific code doesn't seem like a huge deal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.getProperty("home.dir")` to figure out the user's home directory in a non-OS-specific way

Read more about this on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure if I would store login information there.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to store, you may not need a file at all. See

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#userRoot%28%29

or

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#systemRoot%28%29

Comment: Does the preferences API support all OS?

Comment: Do you have a list of each OS you need to support? I would guess it's a requirement of a certified JRE to fulfil this api.

Comment: Well, if it has an official JRE will it support this?

Comment: As commented above, I think it would be a requirement of a JRE to support all of the JRE class library. I don't know this for sure.